# Why is Gesture/Manipulation not working Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows 10 UWP app that is targeted for Windows 10 Mobile but also, I am testing on Microsoft Surface and with my mouse. I simply cannot get the Manipulation to work to detect touch events. Basically, I want to handle swiping inside of a Frame (issue is not the Frame, also tried a rectangle as a test and didn't work also). I CANNOT get any of the events in the code behind to fire when I run the app and try to swipe with my finger or use my mouse. Have tried on multiple devices as well as multiple approaches. For the most part, I am following everything I read on SO and MSDN which makes it even more frustrating. What am I missing here???

This is the XAML for the page. In this example, I set the event handler explicitly in the XAML. However, I have also tried creating it in the code behind for the control. Neither work.

```
         <!--<Rectangle Name="TouchArea" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ManipulationMode="All"/>-->
    <Frame Name="MainPageFrame" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="MainPageFrame_OnManipulationStarted">

    </Frame>
```

Then in the code

```
    private void MainPageFrame_OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Have also tried this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainPageFrame.ManipulationInertiaStarting += MainPageFrame_ManipulationInertiaStarting;
    }

    private void MainPageFrame_ManipulationInertiaStarting(object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cumulative.Translation.X >= 300)
        {
            //Swipe Right
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.Cumulative.Translation.X <= 300)
        {
            //Swipe Left
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Ultimately all I am trying to do is detect when a user swipes inside the frame, with inertia right or left, so I can change Frame.Navigate. This would be similar to how Pivot works but I cannot use Pivot so I am trying to do this instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `Background="Transparent"` for your frame or other element on which you're tracking manipulation. When there is no background set, manipulation events might not be registered properly.

Comment: Wow!!!! This was the issue. Thank you for this. At the same time, I am wondering why 1. This would be the case. Seems silly that you have to set the background for touch events to register. 2. Why Microsoft did not document this in any of the MSDN docs. Thanks again!

Comment: I agree, lack of information on this is puzzling. Glad it helped.